# HDMI port not detected Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've been using my MSI 16GF laptop as a living room media center connected to a Panasonic TV via HDMI for about a year now and it worked perfectly.

Today I tried to turn it on and the TV was dead. After a bit of looking around I found that the HDMI port was not being detected this is the output of xrandr

**xrandr**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.10*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And as you can see the HDMI port is not even detected.

**This is the lspci -v output:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Memory at f7b14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f7b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Memory at f7b1e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7b1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
    Memory at f7b10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: cf200000-cf3fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000cf400000-00000000cf5fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7a00000-f7afffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7b1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] HM87 Express LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7b1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7b19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx

04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at f7900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I've reinstalled Ubuntu and the result is the same. Prior to reinstalling I've tried to switch the nvidia driver, no result, switch to the nouveau driver, no result and to switch the display server back and forth, no result.

Solutions tried:

[HDMI port not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078539/hdmi-port-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)

then reinstall:

https://itsfoss.com/reinstall-ubuntu/

Nvidia drivers tried:
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/

Is my HDMI port broken or am I missing something? What is that I/O port that is detected is it a misconfigured HDMI port ?

Please help I can't face a pandemic without TV.

Answer (score 0):

Well it came back on it's own. I don't understand why. But it did. this is xrandr now:

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.10 +  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
   1920x1080     50.00*+  60.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```