# No HDMI after swapping RAM

Tags: grub2, display

I replaced my RAM because the sticks went bad. For now I put back in the 16gb sticks that came with my desktop, but I plan on going back to 32 once I can get the sticks in. The machine is a Dell Inspiron 5676 that I have been happily dual booting for over a year ( with Ubuntu as my primary OS for development, but using Windows for some gaming and software for the kids' toys) Once I got the new sticks in, Windows works perfectly. Ubuntu gets partway through the boot and then the monitor off HDMI, which is my primary display and sound, says "no input." Both monitors are plugged into the same Radeon card, and there is no on-board video. The card must work, since it works fro GRUB and Windows 10.

The Ubuntu side boots and runs fine, it just won't use the HDMI port. ( I did try adding nomodeset, but that prevented it from booting at all)

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zjHvq9ZHqj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I swapped the RAM it changed some of the BIOS options (legacy boot, tpm etc) which disabled the HDMI drivers. Video is working fine now. (Audio isn't, but I'll post a separate question if I need to)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation a few months ago. I upgraded to 64GB from 32GB. I changed nothing in the BIOS. I could not boot into Ubuntu at all (I do not have Windows).

After a bit (lot?) of hair pulling, I went into the BIOS and changed the ram frequency down (from 3200 to 2666). Computer booted perfectly.

I do not know if you can change things like ram frequency on your Dell, but that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I checked, the freq. is set to 2400, which is the correct setting for this RAM. Also, I made an edit to make it more clear - I can generally boot, but not if I add nomodeset. Without that change I boot just fine, just no second monitor.

Comment: Hmmm...  What is the exact video card? Can you change your primary monitor to the working out (I'm guessing Displayport)? Any GUI settings that can change primary out? Also, have you gone into the Recovery Mode and run dpkg (after enabling networking)? There might be some package that didn't get upgraded properly, and this might fix it.

Comment: I just found this. Might as well give it a try.   https://askubuntu.com/a/1106228/150363

Comment: Ran dpkg, both in recovery and from the full OS. (Also ran boot repair) and no luck. Unfortunately I don't have the right cables to swap which is plugged into which. I've ordered some up, but with everything going on in the world right now that won't be soon.

Comment: Have you tried the linked answer yet? Could work.

Comment: Sorry, yes, gave that a shot as well. I'm tempted to reinstall, but I have a year+ of developer tools and customization on there. It will certainly be an impact.

Comment: I hear you. My 18.04 install is from day one. BTW, which version are you running?

Comment: I'm on 19.10 since October. The install is from ~November 2018